# Java Vector class not updating

Tags: java, vector, jlist

So I'm working on a program for an intro level Java class, and am having an issue when using Vector to dynamically display data to a GUI. We're storing data in a linked list and using the vector to have a dynamic list showing the data members on the side of the GUI. We can add and remove data from the linked list just fine, and when we add to it, the vector automatically updates (we have a call to do that at the end of every successful add and remove). However, when we successfully remove a data member from the linked list, the data stays on the Jlist that the vector is being displayed on. We are required to use vector and cannot use a generic ArrayList.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: How are you creating the JList based upon the Vector?

Comment: Just curious: What made you choose to use the Vector class?

Comment: Sadly the only `Collection` that JList accepts is the outdated `Vector`. But he/she should be using a `ListModel` anyways

Comment: we're using the vector only because our professor told us to :/ but the we use the setListData method inJList to set it to the data in the vector

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `JList` is backed by a `Vector` (by using the `JList(Vector<?> listData)` constructor), the JList will copy the values out of the vector once and never read it again. This means changes to the vector will not be reflected in the JList.

To have your JList dynamically update you'll need to use a ListModel. A common approach is to create a JList with a DefaultListModel, then update the DefaultListModel accordingly. DefaultListModel will fire the appropriate [ListDataEvents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/ListDataEvent.html) when you modify it.

```
DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();
JList jlist = new JList(listModel);
// to update
listModel.addElement("foo");
listModel.addElement("bar");
```